# select all rows tagged with a list of tags

Tags: postgresql, subset

I came up with this query to find all people that where tagged with a certain list of tags:

```
select * from people
where ARRAY[?]::character varying[] <@ ARRAY(
      select tags.name
      from tags
      inner join taggings on tags.id = taggings.tag_id
      where taggings.taggable_type = 'Person' and
            taggings.taggable_id = people.id)
```

Somehow I feel I'm making things too complicated. Right now we don't have enough data for this not to perform well, but is there really not a better way to do it?

**Edit:** Minimal table definitions:

```
create table people (
    id integer
);

create table tags (
    id integer,
    name text
);

create table taggings (
    id integer,
    tag_id integer,
    taggalbe_type text,
    taggable_id integer
);
```

Minimal data:

```
insert into people values (1);
insert into people values (2);
insert into people values (3);

insert into tags values (1, 'foo');
insert into tags values (2, 'bar');
insert into tags values (3, 'baz');

insert into taggings values (1, 1, 'Person', 1);
insert into taggings values (2, 2, 'Person', 1);
insert into taggings values (3, 1, 'Person', 2);
insert into taggings values (4, 2, 'Person', 2);
insert into taggings values (5, 3, 'Person', 2);
```

Now I want e.g. everyone that is tagged with `foo` and `bar`. That would be the person with id 2 in this example.

Comment: please provide sample data to each table in this query.

Comment: And provide table definitions. Like this it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Added table definition and example data. Does this really give you *any* information you couldn't see even more concise in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.id, array_agg(t.name) as tag_name
from
    people p
    inner join
    taggings g on p.id = g.taggable_id
    inner join
    tags t on g.tag_id = t.id
where g.taggable_type = 'Person'
group by p.id
having array['foo','bar']::text[] <@ array_agg(t.name)
;
 id |   tag_name    
----+---------------
  1 | {bar,foo}
  2 | {baz,bar,foo}
```

Comment: Great, except instead of `::text[]` I had to write `::character varying[]` to make it work.